# I can add only 5 google reviews in my Website Due to Pagination, how can i add more with this code

Tags: pagination, review, local-database

I can add only 5 google reviews in my Website Due to Pagination, how can i add more with this code.

**This is My CSS Code**

```
span.review-profile-image {
/*    float: center;*/
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}
span.review-profile-image img {
    /*padding: 15px 15px 20px 20px;*/
    width: 45px;
}

.review-item {
    border: solid 0px;
    /*margin: 7px;*/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 49px -88px 88px #eeeeee;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1192px) {
    .review-item {
    border: solid 0px;
    margin: 7px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #eeeeee;
    }
}

.review-text{
    text-align: justify;
}
.review-author {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight:bold; 
}
.review-date{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #373737;
}
```

this Scrips i Attached

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stevenmonson/googleReviews@6e8f0d794393ec657dab69eb1421f3a60add23ef/google-places.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/google_places.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
        placeId: 'ChIJu0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' //Find placeID @: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id
      , render: ['reviews']
      , min_rating: 4
      , max_rows:5
   });
});
```

I Tried this code but only 5 Reviews Appear on My Website. and also If we can store this reviews to local Database. how Can i Do. Please Let me know if anyone Have idea of this.